# Unable to generate the Auth token using REST Assured

Tags: rest-assured

I am trying to generate an access token for the API which I have hosted locally in my machine.I am able to retrieve the Access token using Postman. But I am unable to do the same using RestAssured.

Below is the code snippet I wrote for the same.

```
Response authentication = RestAssured.given().auth()
.basic("admin", "password123").header("content-type", "application/json")
.when()
.post("http://localhost:3001/auth/");
```

**Response :**

```
 {"reason":"Bad credentials}
```

Please help me to figure out this if am missing anything in this.

Comment: given().auth().preemptive().basic("admin", "password123").when().post("http://localhost:3001/auth/")

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  Response authentication = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive()
>  .basic("admin","password123")
>  .header("content-type", "application/json")
>  .when().post("http://localhost:3001/auth");
> ```

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#basic-authentication